# Using ANOVA with a "Repeated measures" / "Within-subjects" design

Tags: probability-or-statistics

[Repeated measures designs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design) or "Within-Subjects" designs are very important in life sciences and social sciences. Unfortunately, *Mathematica's* ANOVA package is not able to analyze those designs. It only handles "Between-Subjects" type of analyses.

During my whole research career I haven't been able to use *Mathematica* to analyze most of the studies I performed, which really is a pity.

In an e-mail exchange I had with WRI's Andy Ross in the beginning of this year he confirmed that I wasn't overlooking built-in functionality.

The question is: is any one aware of third party packages that handle these types of ANOVAs?

Comment: I don't mean to sound like a jerk, but if you had your "whole research career" to build some tools for this in *Mathematica* why didn't you?  Is the algorithm behind it that prohibitive?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard have you read the linked article? It's sufficiently complex and error-prone that I preferred to use the other tools that I had readily available (Statistica in my case) instead of trying to come up with something myself.

Comment: Okay, just asking.  It went over my head but that didn't surprise me.  I guess it really *is* complex. :^)

Comment: Wouldn't the `GeneralizedLinearModel` be able to handle what ANOVA does, which after all is (more or less) a special form of linear regression?

Comment: @gmr ANOVA's are not used for regression, but are a methodology to compare means of data grouped into categories. However, the cited article describes an alternative approach using GLM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, it's typical that just when you don't need it anymore (as I switched to a totally different discipline), the required functionality pops up. I found that Vol. 13 (2011) of The *Mathematica* Journal contains an article about these types of designs, [Computing Mixed-Design (Split-Plot) ANOVA](https://doi.org/doi:10.3888/tmj.13-17). I thought it good to post it here, as I know many people would love to have this.

Comment: 11 years later, wondering if there's any update to this. For example, is this achievable via [ANOVA[]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/ref/ANOVA.html)? Or still mainly just via the linked package?

Comment: Haven’t checked lately. The ANOVA package still doesn’t seem to have it. There’s an ANOVA ResourceFunction that has the exact same functionality as the package as far as I can see.